# Was "oop" really more common than "oops" till 1990?

Tags: word-usage, history

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oop,oops&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows a marked preference for *oop* over *oops* up until 1990:

[image]

Is Ngrams to be trusted here?  Is it strange that I've never seen *oop* in writing?  Even Dictionary.com doesn't have anything more than acronyms under *[oop](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=oop)*.

Comment: My interpretation: Object Oriented Programming was dominant until 1990, when everyone realized their mistake, and said "oops!"

Comment: "Oops", per the OED, was first used in 1922, possibly as a shortening of "whoops"

Comment: But you can't graph that on NGrams because *whoops* is also a verb, much more common than the interjection.  I tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Click under the graph to get the actual hits. You find

> But I feex you oop goot.
>   And oop there yonder in those trees,
>   dominant faces being ∞p (crystallography; this oo is really infinity),
>   Soo-oop of the ee-evening. Beautiful, beautiful Soup!

as well as a number of other "oop"s, including the call of the sooty grouse. But I didn't see any instances of "oop! I made a mistake." Most of the "oop"s seem to be "up"s spoken with a pronounced accent.

Comment: Oh!  I see I've been misunderstanding NGrams.  I didn't know about those links, either.  At least I can feel better about having never seen it before...

Comment: The first actual hit I looked at has three panes of a window in an illustration highlighted. I knew OCR can be iffy, but that's just ridiculous.

Comment: How many are "allez oop"?

Comment: ...or [Alley Oop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alley_Oop)?

Comment: To confirm @Marthaª's report: [here's the book with the "OOP" window panes](http://books.google.com/books?id=zHdMAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA113&dq=%22oop%22).

Answer (score 3):

[EtymologyOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=oops) says *oops* is only attested from 1933.

To me it is likely to be a shortening of *oops-a-daisy*.  [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/ups-a-daisy.html) tracks that back to *upsa daesy* in "The dialect of Leeds and its neighbourhood" in 1862, to *up a-dazy* from Jonathan Swift in 1711 and to *upaday* even earlier.

If *oop* is a dialect form of *up*, and *oops* of *ups*, then you might not be surprised if *oop* was more common than *oops*, at least until *oops* became part of a set exclamation.

Comment: But it has a completely different meaning from "oops-a-daisy"!

Comment: @Colin: What is the difference between "oops" and  "oops-a-daisy"?